# Can you stretch a Coast Starlight ticket over multiple days?

Tags: tickets, california, amtrak

In September myself and a friend will be travelling from LA up to San Francisco via train, stopping at San Luis Obispo (to see Pismo beach mainly) and later at Salinas (to travel to Monterey and Carmel).

I would like to take the [Coast Starlight](https://www.amtrak.com/coast-starlight-train) train because it (apparently) follows a very scenic route and lets up stop at some nice places. However, we want to stretch the journey out over several days (Friday to Tuesday).

Is it possible to buy one ticket (say, from LA to Emeryville) that will be valid for the several days we plan to travel up the coast, and just hop on/off the Coast Starlight at our stops? Or do we need to buy different tickets for each leg of the journey?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amtrak does not allow stopovers, but they do have a multi-city option on their web site, and if you book one ticket of multiple legs it may be intelligent enough to do better than adding up one-way fares. If you don't book a sleeper berth, the fare is not that high; Los Angeles to Emeryville as low as $50 if booked far in advance. (Note discount tickets may not be refundable.) Also, this train is 100% reserved seats, and may sell out.

Comment: This is really helpful - I used the multi-city route planner and it only came to $72, so it's a good price. I'll try to get it booked in the next day or so. Thanks for your help!